# Conda: How to un-pin packages specified by `anaconda` package?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to update a few commonly used packages in my latest Anaconda installation (release date 2020-07-31, Ubuntu 20.04.1), but I'm seeing error messages complaining that they were pinned by `anaconda` package.

How can I un-pin those and update packages like `matplotlib` or `python`?

## Spec

Python version: `3.8.3`

Conda version: `4.8.4`

## Output

See below. I can see that the `python 3.8.5` package is available in the `pkg/main` channel. But when I tried to update it, I saw the below.

Same happened when I tried to get `matplotlib 3.3.1`.

Is `anaconda` package the problem? I did not have this problem with my previous `Anaconda` install, which was using python `3.7` so a while ago.

```
conda search python

#output

python                         3.8.5 h4d41432_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.5 h6f2ec95_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.5 h6f2ec95_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.8.5      hcff3b4d_0  pkgs/main   
....

conda update python

# output

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: | 

Updating python is constricted by 

anaconda -> requires python==3.8.3=hcff3b4d_2

If you are sure you want an update of your package either try `conda update --all` or install a specific version of the package you want using `conda install <pkg>=<version>`

done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

Here's my `.condarc`:

```
channels:
  - defaults
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you try what the message suggests? `conda install python=3.8.5`?

Comment: Tried. conda ended up solving for environment forever, I gave up in the end..

Comment: Have you tied the `--no-pin` option?

Comment: @WillZ Try mamba. It's a drop-in replacement for conda with a much faster solver.